# How do I complete a task in intellij with the JIRA plugin?

Tags: intellij-idea, jira

Expected behavior:

- Complete and close the task.
- Commit changes
- Remove change list
- Mark Jira as resolved

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer.
To complete a tasks press the following key board shortcut:
Alt-Shift-W